# not able to load static files using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

her is my app.js which is confugaration file of express.js

<

```
var express = require('express')
  , argv = require("optimist").argv
  , fs = require("fs")
  , hbs = require("hbs")
  , WatsonClient = require("watson-js");


var clientId        = argv.key || '5b1cb9a9c097e1100eeeebaf66117265'
  , clientSecret    = argv.secret || '01b8417ac6872450'
  , appPort         = argv.port || '3000';


function cp(source, destination, callback) {

    // Read a buffer from `source`
    fs.readFile(source, function(err, buf) {
        if (err) { return callback(err); }

        // Write that buffer to the new file `destination`
        fs.writeFile(destination, buf, callback);
    })
}


var Watson = new WatsonClient.Watson({ client_id: clientId, client_secret: clientSecret });


var app = express();


app.configure(function() {
    console.log('inside function');
    // Set the location of views and type of view engine
    app.set('views',__dirname + '/app/views');
        console.log(__dirname + '/app/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);
       console.log('after view');

    // Set up a standard Express configuration
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: "This is an example."
    }));
    app.use(app.router);
    console.log('before public');
    // Set the location of static assets
    app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
        console.log(__dirname+'/public');
        console.log('after public');

});


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('layout');
});


app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {


    cp(req.files.upload_file.filename.path, __dirname + req.files.upload_file.filename.name, function() {


        res.send({ saved: 'saved' });
    });
});

app.post('/speechToText', function(req, res) {

    // Traditionally, you would store this access token somewhere safe like a database. For the purposes of this example, we're going to generate a new one on the first request and store it in the session so we don't have to deal with a database or tracking expiry and refreshing access tokens.
    if(!req.session.accessToken) {

        // !AT&T API: Get Access Token
        Watson.getAccessToken(function(err, accessToken) {
            if(err) {
                // Handle an error getting an access token
                res.send(err);
                return;
            } else {
                req.session.accessToken = accessToken;

                token.
                Watson.speechToText(__dirname + '/public/audio/audio.wav', req.session.accessToken, function(err, reply) {
                    if(err) {

                        res.send(err);
                        return;
                    }

                    res.send(reply);
                    return;
                });
            }
        });
    } else {

        Watson.speechToText(__dirname + '/public/audio/audio.wav', req.session.accessToken, function(err, reply) {
            if(err) {

                res.send(err);
                return;
            }

            return;
        });
    }
});


app.listen(appPort);
console.log('AT&T Speech API Basic Walkthrough App started on Port ' + appPort + '.');
```

// !USAGE: node app.js --key= --secret= --port=

// !SETUP: Dependencies
/*
 * Express:     Minimal web application framework
 * FS:          Node.js File System module
 * Optimist:    Lightweight option parsing
 * HBS:         Express View Engine wrapper for Handlebars
 * Watson.js:   Simple API Wrapper for the AT&T Speech API
 */

and my layout.html is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>AT&amp;T Speech API Example: Basic Walkthrough</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Application for the AT&T Speech API Deep Dive Presentation at DevLab 2012">
    <meta name="author" content="Michael Owens">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/styles/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/styles/example-basic.css">
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
     <a  onclick="Recorder.playBack('audio');" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Play">
                                             Play
                                         </a> 
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <h2 id="progress-title">Progress (Step <span id="progress-step">1</span> of 5)</h2>
            <div id="progress-indicator" class="progress progress-striped">
                <div class="bar" style="width: 20%;"></div>
            </div>
            <ol class="progress-list">
                <li id="progress-01" class="active">Access User's Microphone</li>
                <li id="progress-02">Record Audio from Mic</li>
                <li id="progress-03">Save Audio to File</li>
                <li id="progress-04">POST File to AT&amp;T Speech API</li>
                <li id="progress-05">Receive Results from AT&amp;T Speech API</li>
            </ol>
            <div>
                <a href="/" class="btn"><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Start Over</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span8">
            <h2>Current Status</h2>
            <div id="status-mic" class="alert alert-info">
                Audio Status: <strong>waiting</strong>
            </div>
            <div id="status-upload" class="alert alert-info">
                File Status: <strong>waiting</strong>
            </div>
            <div id="control_panel">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button id="button-connect" class="btn btn-large btn-success"><i class="icon-off icon-white"></i> <span class="action">Connect</span></button>
                    <button id="button-recorder" class="btn btn-large" disabled="disabled"><i class="icon-music"></i> <span class="action">Record</span></button>
                    <span id="button-save" class="btn">
                        <button disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-large"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i> <span class="action">Save</span></button>
                        <span id="save_button"><span id="flashcontent"></span></span>
                    </span>
                    <button id="button-transcribe" class="btn btn-large" disabled="disabled"><i class="icon-share-alt"></i> <span class="action">Transcribe</span></button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="transcribe-container">
                <h2>Speech API Response</h2>
                <div id="transcribe-response"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="/upload" >
        <input name="authenticity_token" value="xxxxx" type="hidden">
        <input name="upload_file[parent_id]" value="1" type="hidden">
        <input name="format" value="json" type="hidden">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/scripts/example-basic.js"></script>




</div>


</body>
</html>
```

When i run app.js on node in cmd, it gives me error of not able to load static files  i.e js and css files but it load view part i.e layout.html

exact errors is

<

GET h://ip:3000/public/scripts/swfobject.js 404 (Not Found)

GET h://ip:3000/public/scripts/example-basic.js 404 (Not Found)

GET h://ip:3000/public/styles/bootstrap.css 404 (Not Found)

GET h://ip:3000/public/styles/example-basic.css 404 (Not Found)

>

ip -localhost
h -https

my foldr structute is

example(parent folder)

subfolders

app/views/layout.html(code is given above)

public/scripts/js files

public/styles/css files

app.js(code is given above)

all the above subfolder(app,public,app.js) at the same level

so please suggest me some thing

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you remove the 'public' from your URLs, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/example-basic.css">
```

You setup the static directory to be `/public` so its going to look in there for static resources. You did that here:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

When you add `public` to those URLs, it will be looking in `/public` for a folder called `public`, which it won't find. It will however find a folder called `styles`.

Comment: @monish having problems again? Why remove the accepted answer?

Comment: If you are having new problems, create a new question. Don't update your old question to a new question.